Weighted F1-score
I'm training and validating models for a binary classification problem in a dataset that has great class imbalance.
When searching for metrics for evaluating the performance of the models, I found that the weighted F1-Score could be a potential solution to have a "less biased" result.
Nevertheless, I couldn't find any academic paper where the weighted F1-Score was explained in detailed. Does anybody have any reference?

This might be the wrong Stack for this type of question.  If you have code that needs to be fixed, Stackoverflow is the place to post this question.  However,  questions such as how do i do the whole thing are not accepted usually, and with luck will be moved instead of just dead-end closed.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
